# Positioning / aligning middle elements in 3-column layout

Tags: css, positioning, vertical-alignment, alignment

Here's my current markup: http://jsfiddle.net/LcMU3/64/.

I am having issues with positioning / aligning elements in the middle column.

First, I want to vertically align the elements in the middle and also horizontally center.

Second, I want to "float" the arrows to the left and right of the "weekLabel".

Ultimately, it would look like this:

[image]

I actually did try positioning and aligning the elements in nested 3-column layout, but the main issue I have with this approach is the HTML markup gets difficult to follow with all the nested divs.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you allowed to rewrite your markup in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as a `display:inline-block` since a `div` by default is `display:block`

```
.weekLabel{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.leftArrow {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

.rightArrow {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/LcMU3/67/

you have to give these elements a float:left; and assign an text-align:center to the weeklabel to center the text, and some margins to finish it off:

```
.leftArrow {
    float:left
}

.rightArrow {
    float:left;
}

.weekLabel{
float:left;
text-align:center;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: ah, cool...why three left floats? this addresses the positioning...what about the alignment? can I just use line-height on the middle col class?

Comment: Left floats don't have to intend placing something at the left side. It just means something like: placing objects next to each other from left to right. Yes you could use lineheight, but you could make it yourself a lot easier if you placed the background on the wrapper, I'll give you a new jsfiddle soon for demo.  http://jsfiddle.net/LcMU3/68/

Answer (score 0):

Combo `inline-block`/`vertical-align` FTW:

```
.leftArrow,.rightArrow,.weekLabel {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

(beware of the `#wrapper`'s width)